# How to create and connect a custom component theme for Native Base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using Native Base 2.0+, the themes are ejected and using StyleProvider I am able to tweak and customize any Native Base component according to my theme, no problem.

Following the [docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#Customize), it's stated that to add themes to a **custom component** we should define a namespace for said component and merge it with the instantiated styling as well. Code example below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Title, Text, connectStyle } from 'native-base'
import Colors from '../Themes/Colors'
import ApplicationStyles from '../Themes/ApplicationStyles'

class NBHeader extends Component {
  render () {
    const styles = this.props.style
    return (
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Text style={styles.headerBackButton}>
              {'< Back'}
            </Text>
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Login</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right />
      </Header>
    )
  }
}

export default connectStyle('CustomComponents.Header', ApplicationStyles)(NBHeader)
```

In this case, namespace for the component is 'CustomComponents.Header'. Then, we use StyleProvider to connect the Theme:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleProvider } from 'native-base';
class CustomComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // connect styles to props.style defined by the theme
      const styles = this.props.style;
      <StyleProvider style={customTheme}>
        Your Custom Components
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
}
// Define your own Custom theme
const customTheme = {
  'yourTheme.CustomComponent': {
    // overrides CustomComponent style...
  }
};
```

Since I've ejected the theme, I entered the new namespace for the Custom Component in NB's Theme file, so it should already be added and cascaded using StyleProvider.

So for instance, if I want the header to be 'red' and have a padding of '10' due to theming rules, I add those as default props of **'CustomComponents.Header'** and forget about it, it will always be applied to the component as long as the StyleProvider is cascading themes.

The problem is I cannot get this defined Custom Component's default theme to be applied. I don't know if it's a problem with my code or how Native Base works. Any help would be appreciated and I can provide further code if needed.